# /etc/services file accidentally deleted on Amazon Linux EC2 instance

Tags: configuration, yum, data-recovery, amazon-linux

I accidentally deleted `/etc/services` file from my ec2 instance on AWS running `Amazon Linux`.

How can I restore this file?
In `Ubuntu`, I found out that this can be done using `netbase` package, how can this be achieved in `Amazon Linux`(centOS flavor) ?

Comment: find rpm name -  `rpm -qf /etc/services` in my case its `setup-2.8.71-7.amzn2.noarch` then please go through - https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/setup-2.8.71-9.el7.noarch.rpm.html

Comment: @sanjayparmar That link is not for Amazon Linux.

Comment: @Mandeep Singh , package name is same on both. it was tested on my AWS instance

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the file from another instance, or because it is part of the `setup` package, you can run:

```
yum reinstall setup
```